# Efficient way to get some files from AzureDevops repository and upload them to Azure Blob Store's container

Tags: java, azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-storage

Suppose I have a repository in **AzureDevops** in which the structure is like some folders are having the json files inside them.
Ex:

```
Folder A: 
         File1.json
         File2.json
Folder B:
         File3.json
Folder C:
         File4.json
```

I need to fetch these files from the repository and place it in the existing **Azure Storage Account** containers named: **Folder A, Folder B, Folder C**.

Please provide an optimal solution using **java**. I tried several ways which includes:

1. Cloning of whole repo in local FS and then uploading files one by one to blob.
2. Used Azure Devops rest APIs to fetch the contents of the file one by one and the uploaded each on the blob in there respective blob name. However this leads to hitting of REST APIs number of files +1 times.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same? We are also looking for the same way, where all the repos in the project or collection need to be scanned  and certain file need to be uploaded to the Fileshare.

Answer (score 1):

> Efficient way to get some files from AzureDevops repository and upload them to Azure Blob Store's container

There this a task [Azure File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops), which could be used to copy files to Microsoft Azure storage blobs or virtual machines (VMs).

[image]

You could check [this document](https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/publishing-static-content-to-azure-blob-storage) for some more details.

Comment: is there any dynamic way  to scan all the repos and get specific files or a specific document is uploaded to fileshare with automated pipelines?